# Extension Function Constructor Parameter Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods

How is it possible to create extension function with a parameter of constructor of an extended class

This solutions doesn't compile. As `this` cant have a parameter there. How should I change code to pass it?

```
fun JSONObject.parseKey(param: String?): String {
    return this(param).getString("key")
}
```

Comment: It doesn’t make sense to define this as an extension function because extension functions are called on instances.

Comment: Ok, then how can I make an extension function like this with JSONObject instance?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve? I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you explain the use case?

Comment: Why would you want to call it on a JSONObject instance when it doesn’t use the instance for anything? Why don’t you just directly call the JSONObject constructor in your function and remove the receiver?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here.

You could make it a top-level function like this:

```kotlin
fun parseKey(param: String?): String {
    return JSONObject(param).getString("key")
}

// usage
val value = parseKey("...")
```

Or drop the `param` argument and use the existing `JSONObject` receiver:

```kotlin
fun JSONObject.getMyKey(): String {
    return getString("key")
}

// usage
val value = JSONObject("...").getMyKey()
```